# How can I tell how often Google crawls my site?

Tags: website, google, web-crawler

I've started a relatively new website, and I submitted it to google and everything. I use google's webmaster tools as well. I'm wondering how to figure out the frequency of google's spider accessing my website. I always hear people talking in forums about "I'm getting 250 pages crawled an hour" and so on... Is there software to use? A javascript method similar to google analytics? Or is there something to analyze my server's logs?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just check the webserver logs if the visitor's [`User-Agent`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) request header matches/contains [`Googlebot`](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Googlebot/). There are lot of [webserver log analyzer tools](http://google.com/search?q=web+server+log+analyzer), either free or payware. Most of them are also able to categorize bots. From them all I've had the best experience with [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can you tell me what the log file will probably be named? I'm using a 1and1 server and I'm fairly new to the web hosting game

Comment: You're using 3rd party hosting? Well, contact them for more details or poke a bit round in the hosting's control panel.

Comment: By the way, with Google Analytics you don't need to know about webserver logs at all. It runs completely independently.

Answer (score 2):

Signup for Google Webmaster Central, aka Webmasters Tools, verify your site, and wait for the stats to appear.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly unlikely Google Bot will run any Javascript on your site that will track it arriving, so the best hope is to look at the site logs themselves - either in webalizer or the hundreds of other log file parsers, or just open them up in a texteditor and run a regex to extract the Google Bot user agent.

You should see then how many hits it makes in a space of time. If it's too much you might want to look at using an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it would run any javascript. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

[AWstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a good, free utility to use for log file analysis. It'll give you a lot of interesting statistics in addition to the Google crawl info.

Comment: Ah, I just found this piece of software... It looks like it'll do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the solution you're going with, you should accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Google analytics, it covers all visits to your site and you can work out whether a visitor was a bot or not.  It is also excellent for SEO on your site helping to increase visitors.

Comment: Google Analytics doesn't include bots because it uses javascript, which bots generally don't execute.

Answer (score 0):

> AWstats is a good, free utility to use for log file analysis. It'll give you a lot of interesting statistics in addition to the Google crawl info.

[Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool indeed

Answer (score 0):

Check this article which tells how to [send mail when Googlebot crawls a webpage of your website](http://www.expertsguide.info/2010/08/send-mail-when-googlebot-crawls-a-webpage/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use googles webmaster tools, It will tell you how often the bot has crawled your site...